# Escaping Ocal literals in strings

Tags: javascript, string, octal

I am trying to use `\1` in a string, but JavaScript interprets it as an octal literal `\u0001`.

How can I override this so `\1` is just interpreted as `\1`?

Comment: try escapping '\\1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double backslash:

```js
console.log("\\1");
```